# How to check existence Extras in Intent

Tags: android

When I try to get Extras, I get Fatal Eroorr

```
try{
        Sdacha=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Sdacha");
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e){}
```

How can I check existence Extras?

Comment: can u post log with error?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this,

```
if(getIntent().getExtras().containsKey("Sdacha"))
        {
        String  preview=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Sdacha");

        }
```

**EDIT**

Also as Evos suggested, one more layer of Null check can also be added to the above code.If you are sure that the extras will not be null, then the above approach is good. If not follow the below one.

```
 if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null)
        {
        if(getIntent().getExtras().containsKey("Sdacha"))
        {
        String  preview=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Sdacha");
        }
        }
```

Comment: I think this will also cause `NullPointerException` if `Extras` is `null`

Answer (score 3):

It's easy just check that `Extras` is not null before getting something from it:

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null){
     Sdacha=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Sdacha");
}
```

Comment: What if I have another Extras but not "Sdacha"?

Comment: Well, you can have only one `Extras` bundle in intent, so if you need fetch other data just put one more line of code in this block

Answer (score 1):

```
 Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
 if (bundle != null) {
      String preview = bundle.getString("Sdacha");
      if (preview != null) {
          // do anything  .....
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this from happening, I like to encapsulate my calls into a static startActivity method, the same pattern as the newInstance() in fragments:

```
public static void startActivity(Activity activity, int param, int flags){
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(flags);
    intent.putExtra(PARAM, param);
    activity.startActivity(intent);
}
```

And of course if you use this method from other activities, you'll never have a NPE.